# MS SQL Server Service Does not start

Tags: sql-server, service

```
Log Name:      System
Source:        Service Control Manager
Date:          11/1/2011 2:01:13 PM
Event ID:      7000
Task Category: None
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      Admin-PC
Description:

The SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS) service failed to start due to the following error: 
The system cannot find the file specified.

Event Xml: <Event
 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">  
 <System>
     <Provider Name="Service Control Manager" Guid="{555908d1-a6d7-4695-8e1e-26931d2012f4}" EventSourceName="Service
 Control Manager" />
     <EventID Qualifiers="49152">7000</EventID>
     <Version>0</Version>
     <Level>2</Level>
     <Task>0</Task>
     <Opcode>0</Opcode>
     <Keywords>0x8080000000000000</Keywords>
     <TimeCreated SystemTime="2011-11-01T08:31:13.333398700Z" />
     <EventRecordID>176909</EventRecordID>
     <Correlation />
     <Execution ProcessID="556" ThreadID="5360" />
     <Channel>System</Channel>
     <Computer>Admin-PC</Computer>
     <Security />   </System>   <EventData>
     <Data Name="param1">SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS)</Data>
     <Data Name="param2">%%2</Data>   </EventData> </Event>
```

Comment: Next time try putting this into an actual question, rather than a statement.

Answer (score 1):

Check the properties for the service, specifically the "path to executable" value.  Verify that the file reference in that value actually exists.

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced same problem and i have resolved just stopping SQL Browsing service.

So give it a try.